# Does it make sense to have 'but of course' as the start of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

I have this text-

> The whole purpose to this "selective breeding" is simply to improve a humans, and in doing so usually the dogs, way of life. If we carry the example of the border collie then it's clear that these dogs have simplified the lives of farmers by rounding up their flock for them in an efficient and highly effective way, saving the effort of doing it by hand. **But of course** the ways that human life has been improved by the selective breeding of dogs, doesn’t end with herding.

I was wondering if it is correct, grammatically, to start a sentence with a conjunction in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense to start a sentence like this with "but of course". According to this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20of%20course&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20of%20course%3B%2Cc0), This expression is widely used and, if you look at actual instances, a significant proportion are at the start of a sentence- including works by D.H Lawrence and H. G. Wells.

It is conventional to put the **of course** between commas, thus:

> But, of course, most of the dilemmas that editors face involve tangled, complicated situations that defy simple answers. [The layers of magazine editing](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=wxbBY7FkDHkC&pg=PA94&dq=%22but%20of%20course%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9y7KK-ubZAhVJLZoKHYuqAWI4KBDoAQhEMAU)

Answer (score 0):

> But, of course,

means

> Obviously, however,

and is just as grammatical and idiomatic.

I do remember hearing decades ago stylistic advice not to start an independent sentence with "And" or "But." Those were suggestions on style rather than rules of grammar, and opinions differ on style. Moreover, suggestions on style are best interpreted as meaning "seldom do" rather than "never do" or as meaning "usually do" rather than "always do." I strive for parallelism in my own prose, but will neglect it if it makes a sentence verbose.

If you were to ask my opinion of the passage as whole, my *opinion* is that it is not well written, but that the introductory phrase of "but of course" is not where I would start critiquing.